# Android adapter that implements Filterable does not show results

Tags: android, textview, android-filterable

I have a custom adapter that is used to filter results for search. This works fine for finding auto-complete search tags. However, it has been modified to show recently searched items when the user first touches the search text view. The filtering process is initiated by setting the text to "" in the search textView:

```
TextView.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            searchTextView.setText("");
            recentSearches = true;

            return false;
        }
    };
```

There is also a Textwatcher:

```
TextWatcher onSearchSuggestionTextChanged = new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            if (s.length() > 0)
            {
             recentSearches = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            if (!recentSearches && s.length() == 0)
            {
                cancelSearch();
            }
        }
    };
```

The search textView is initialised as follows:

```
searchTextView.setAdapter(new SearchAdapter(this));
searchTextView.addTextChangedListener(onSearchSuggestionTextChanged);
searchTextView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
```

And the SearchAdapter is:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
{
    private Context context;
    private List<FoundItem> resultList = new ArrayList<FoundItem>();
    private List<FoundItem> recentSearches = null;

    public SearchAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public FoundItem getItem(int index)
    {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        }

        FoundItem item = getItem(position);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.name());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        Filter filter = new Filter()
        {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
            {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null)
                {
                    List<FoundItem> items = findSuggestions(context, constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = items;
                    filterResults.count = items.size();
                }
                else
                {
                    filterResults.values = getRecentSearches();
                    filterResults.count = getRecentSearches().size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
            {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0)
                {
                    resultList = (List<FoundItem>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    private List<FoundItem> findSuggestions(Context context, String query)
    {
        ...
        return foundItems;
    }

    private List<FoundItem> getRecentSearches()
    {
        ...
        return recentSearches;
    }
```

The adapter does get results for recent searches, so the `performFiltering` and `publishResults` methods are called as expected but then only the `getCount` method is called once and no results are displayed. In contrast, the autocomplete items are displayed as expected when typing in a few characters. Note that the recent searches are not null and when calling
`searchTextView.getAdapter().getCount()` before and after the text change the correct number of previous searches is returned.

So why does it not display the results? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Manually we do have to call

```
onSearchSuggestionTextChanged.onTextChanged()
```

inside the ontouch(action_down) of the edittext and if text in it has length zero!

Which would inturn fire all the events of filter

```
TextView.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        searchTextView.setText("");
        recentSearches = true;
        onSearchSuggestionTextChanged.onTextChanged("",0,0,0);
        return false;
    }
};
```